# Vertices connection of Assignment Problem in Bipartite Graph

Tags: graph-theory, operations-research, bipartite-graphs

I'm doing a C++ project that requires solving the Assignment Problems.
During the study of the subject I have a doubt, is it possible that in any assignment problem, one or more arcs that connect any pair of left and right vertices are not there?

Let me explain better, taking into consideration the cost matrix is ​​it possible that some cells are equal to zero to indicate the absence of an arc that connects a left vertex to a right vertex?

Or Does it necessarily have to be that in the assignment problems in the bipartite graph every vertex must be connected to every vertex of the opposite side and therefore have a positive cost?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, there is no requirement that every possible arc exist. Note, though, that if not all arcs exist it might be impossible to form a complete assignment (meaning the problem might be infeasible).

Textbooks will typically assume a complete bipartite graph (all possible arcs present) when defining the assignment problem, so this may be a gray area of terminology.  If you want to confine yourself to the textbook definition, an alternative to omitting an arc would be to include it with a cost so large that it would be prohibitively costly to select that arc. (If the arc is selected anyway in an optimal solution, then omitting the arc makes the problem infeasible.)

Comment: So, in other words, there is the possibility that if I do not include all possible edges in the bipartite graph it will not have any possible solution for the assignment problem. Correct?

Comment: Yes. For instance, suppose the source nodes are A, B, C, the sink nodes are 1, 2, 3, and the only arcs coming from A and C both go to node 2. Since only one source can be matched with sink 2, the problem is infeasible.

Comment: Ok. And what if I assign to each left vertices at least one right vertices in order to generate a correct bipartite graph, does this situation always have a solution?

Comment: In my previous example, include arcs from B to all three sinks (1, 2, 3), for a total of five arcs. Every left vertex has an arc to at least one right vertex, but there is still no solution, for the reason stated above.

Comment: Yes sorry, I explained myself wrong, I was wondering if in case each left and right vertex has at least one edge connection with some opposite vertices, does this situation still have a solution?

Comment: In what way does my example not satisfy that hypothesis?

Comment: Ok I got it. However put the question in other way what are the constraint to make an assignment problem be fesible. The reson of this question is because I'm doing a benchmark on the auction algorithm and maxiomum weighterd matching.

Comment: Obviously, having all possible arcs is a sufficient condition for the problem to be feasible. I'm not aware of any useful set of conditions that is both necessary and sufficient.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your time and help!